# Python is not able to compare two values

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
a=999999
b=999999
if a is b:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

The answer to the following code is no.

Why python is not able to compare a and b inspite of the fact that both the values are equal to 999999

Comment: because `a` *is not* `b` however `a==b` is true

Comment: `a is b` is checking if objects a and b are same (or memory locations of a and b are same) if you want to check if there values are same you have use` ==` instead of is

Comment: I suggest you print `id(a)` and `id(b)`.

Comment: Python *is able* to compare two values, you just didn't tell it to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to compare two values for *equality* is:

```
a == b
```

When you use `is`, you're comparing object identity, not equality.

Comment: then why does  `is`  works for lower values ?

Comment: @HabibAnsari because small integers are pooled, and in that case the identity check succeeds. See this article: https://davejingtian.org/2014/12/11/python-internals-integer-object-pool-pyintobject/

Answer (score 1):

Try this...!

```
a=999999
b=999999
if a == b:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if the two variables are the same obect with is.  You are most likely looking for `==`

`a == b`

Comment: then why does `is` works for lower values such as 4 ?